# Using Unicode Character 'ELEMENT OF' (U+2208) in Notepad++

Tags: unicode, notepad++, symbols

I'm trying to use Unicode Character 'ELEMENT OF' (U+2208) in notepad++
As seen here --> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2208/index.htm

It should be the symbol much like a E and then there's another one munch like a E with s / through it to denote "not a element of"
The issue I have is that using Alt+2208 creates 'á'.

Copying it form a source such as a webpage and pasting it over displays a '2'

Is there anyway to use special characters such as the one above?
Trying to make notes on my computational maths lectures and it just doesn't seem possible in notepad++ and sadly I prefer using it over word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind guys, managed to find out what the issue was..

If anyone has this issue, try changing your font in notepad++.

Turns out that the font I was using didn't seem to have all of the characters that I required, a simple change of font seemed to fix the issue. 
I changed to "Cambria" font and currently it seems to all be good :)

Settings > Style Config > Global Styles > Global Override > Font name > Cambria
Then Tick "Enable global font" and save and close the window.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [<kbd>ALT-<numeric_keypad></kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) produces characters two ways, neither of which are Unicode code points in hexadecimal, which is what U+2208 represents.

The number is in decimal and must be typed from the numeric keypad.  If it has a leading zero, it is interpreted from Windows' current ANSI code page.  On US Windows, that is cp1252.  If it does not have a leading zero, it is interpreted as the current OEM code page used in the windows console.  On US Windows, that is cp437.

Example from Notepad++ on US Windows:

```
ALT-128  Ç  Correct for [cp437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)
ALT-0128 €  Correct for [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
```

ALT-2208 returns á, which is ALT-160.  Code pages have 256 entries.  160 is the remainder of 2208/256, so that makes sense.  The codes wrap around.

With the wrong encoding or font selected, Notepad++ usually produces a replacement character such as a question mark, box, or boxed question mark.  Cambria does include `∈`, for example, but Consolas does not.