# how to add person with disability (PwD) symbol to tesseract dataset

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am working on license plate recognition using python. I worked with tesseract for doing OCR recognition.For my project i wish to include person with disability symbol in tesseract library. I reviewed the following links for updating the tesseract library [tutorial for tesseract library update](http://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/)
I followed the steps for creating tff file but failed by notifying the image is not prescribed font.
I understood from the studied literature people added various types of fonts and number style and couldn't find the information about how to add image into tesseract data set.
Can anyone suggest me how could i succeed in adding the image to tesseract data set? I am grateful if someone provided me the links or information pertaining to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To train for new data in tesseract library you need the following packages (i) jTessBoxEditor (ii)notepad++ (iii) serak trainer

jTessBoxEditor can be downloaded from here[jTessBoxEditordownload link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vietocr/files/jTessBoxEditor/) which also requires runtime java environment. It accepts input as .txt format.

You can use notepadd++ to enter the special characters. The procedures to enter the characters can be found from [how to enter characters in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876011/using-unicode-character-element-of-u2208-in-notepad) For example, to enter PwD symbol you might press ALT key hold down then entered +9855 from numberpad, the symbol will appear in notepad++. After entering the characters save as .txt type.

Open the jTessBoxEditor and click Tiff/Box Generator to feed the .txt file as input, also change the font style that supports your character. For Pwd symbol i choose segoeuisymbol. the tif will be stored in the folder where the .txt file created. 
                                                                      To train the tessdata you need seraktrainer which can be downloaded from [serak download link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/) The procedures for using serak trainer can be found from the video[serak trainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_1-hGsXxy8) It explains step by step procedure for creating tessdata i.e trained data file

Hope this can be useful for someone